# I Installed Ubuntu boot loader at windows partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

a noob here. I just dual booted Ubuntu on my laptop, and simply following the instruction on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPUVIc-W13s it says to install the boot loader to windows (loader) which is /dev/sda3 ntfs Windows (my case). Which i've done. I am quite scared because many other tutorials said to install it on the hardisk and use a software to get dual boot option. But i don't have error and the GRUB? is opening. And i can still open windows 10.

The question is, If i uninstall ubuntu will there be an error, also how to fix it! i'm unsure either to be relaxed or stressed right now, ALSO here is my DISK partitions with a partition i'm unsure what is. (yes i know it's quite a mess)
[All my partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15yeL.png)

Comment: Is your machine in BIOS (legacy) or UEFI mode? The video is (at 16 minutes) longer than I care to spend time on, so I am not sure what was suggested to you and why (maybe include the time-offset with the revelant part(s)?). Have you tried [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)? Please update you question with a link to the pastebin URL with the results.

Comment: The screenshot shows an uefi-partitioned HDD but the video demonstrates, AFAICT, a bios installation into a vmware virtual machine, so it seems that the video gave you bad advice. Boot from a ubuntu boot stick and mount the small first partition, which you van probably do by double-clicking its icon. I expect that this partition contains an EFI/Microsoft directory with windows boot files. If that is the case, your windows installation should be safe. But it won't hurt to make an image backup of windows first, e.g. with macrium reflect free.